# Is there any way to access Firebase raw event data prior to linking to BigQuery?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I need to access raw event data stored in Firebase. Thus, I have linked Firebase to Bigquery last month. Bigquery currently creates daily tables containing event data for a month. However, as the Bigquery documentation states, it is not possible to import data prior to linking to Bigquery. Does anyone know how these data can be exported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact dataset from prior to linking cannot be exported in anyway.

The only workaround is that if you want to look up specific information, you can try using the [GA4 Data API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1) to fetch the information. Again, this will not give you the entire dataset export.